# Use iCloud Drive as a backup of finished work

Tags: mac, icloud, backup

I have hundreds, if not thousands of completed projects on my Mac. I backup to an external hard-drive, using Time Machine. And once a month to a different external hard-drive, again using Time Machine, which I store off-site.

I would also like to use iCloud Drive to backup my completed projects to.

I presume all I would need to do is copy over the complete projects to the iCloud Drive folder? The projects will then be on my Macs hard drive AND a copy on iCloud?

Is this correct or am I missing something?

I don't need to synch the files with another computer or device. I don't need to backup documents I'm working on. All I want is to backup finished work to the cloud.

UPDATE

If I copy over my completed work to the iCloud Drive folder, I fear this will take up twice the amount of hard-disk space on my Mac: on my local work folder AND in the iCloud Drive folder. Even if I turn on 'Optimise Mac Storage' documents in the iCloud Drive folder will only be stored in iCloud when space is needed. I have just about enough space, so hence my work will take up TWICE the amount of hard disk space.

All I want is to store a copy of my work off-site on Apple servers. Any ideas how to do this?

UPDATE 2

It seems that there is no way to store copies of files on iCloud Drive ONLY on Apple servers in the cloud (without them also taking up room on my Macs local hard-drive).

So instead I'm going to use OneDrive. I'd prefer to use Apple, but I can't.

Comment: iCloud Drive is not a backup.  It is a not-very-reliable sync service.

Comment: I understand it is 'sold' as a sync service. But presumably I can use it as a place to put a copy of my completed projects?

Comment: You can, but if you ever delete one from the Mac, all copies of it online & synced to other devices will also be deleted.

Comment: You can right-click folders in iCloud Drive and select "Remove Download" to leave them stored in iCloud but remove them from your local drive. If you don't want the files twice on your Mac, is there a reason why you *copy* your files into iCloud Drive instead of *moving* them?

Comment: I want a copy (backup) in the cloud. Thanks for your suggestion. So could I go to my 'parent' folder called 'work' on iCloud Drive (which contains all my files) and with one right-click 'remove downloads' from my local drive? That sounds promising

Answer (score 2):

iCloud Drive appears as another 'hard drive' on the Mac, so it would function much like an external drive. So in your case, copying those projects to iCloud Drive would indeed work. It would function as a form of backup, in the sense an external hard drive would, with the benefit of it being offsite.

Of course, this does not include the syncing and automation functions of backup software, but it would be a fine idea as a secondary copy of older projects.

Personally I would not use just iCloud, nor any other single storage form as my only backup, I would prefer an additional backup methods as well, just in case.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you **copy** the files to the iCloud folder you should then have 3 versions: 1 in your local work folder, 1 in the iCloud Drive folder on your Mac (iCloud may delete this local version to make room, depending on settings), and 1 stored off-site on Apple's servers.

Comment: Yes, I think you have highlighted a problem with my idea. I don't want my work to take up twice the amount of hard-disk space on my Mac. On my local work folder AND in the iCloud Drive folder (on my Macs hard-drive). Even if I turn on 'Optimise Mac Storage' documents will be stored only in iCloud when space is needed. I have just about enough space, so hence my work will take up TWICE the amount of hard disk space. All I want is to store a copy of my work off-site on Apple servers. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Don't use Apple servers, they're not designed for it. iCloud is a sync service, not a backup or storage service.